# Why does Google Chrome Lighthouse say my AMP carousel list items (<li>) are not contained within <ul> or <ol> parent element?

Tags: html, google-chrome, amp-html, lighthouse

I am using the AMP-carousel component on a website to show related products.

An example page: https://www.bizzlibrary.com/Template/MW1XT/gdpr-bring-your-own-device-byod-policy/

When I run Google Chrome Lighthouse, it reports back the following for each of our template pages

```
"List items (<li>) are not contained within <ul> or <ol> parent elements."
```

In source view everything looks great. All the `<li>` are within a `<ul>`. When inspecting the elements the only thing I noticed is that AMP added a role:

```
<ul class="list-reset amp-carousel-slide amp-scrollable-carousel-slide" **role="listitem"** aria-hidden="false" style="scroll-snap-align: start; transform: translate(0px, 0px); --content-transform:translate(0px, 0px) !important;">
```

It adds the `role="list item"`

On Github I read these roles might be problem: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/issues/9643

Is this a AMP-Carousel bug, a Chrome Lighthouse bug, or is it just bad coding on the website? Any solution would be welcome.

Comment: Have you set a class on the wrong element by any chance? The `amp-carousel-slide` class looks like (I am only making an educated guess here) it should appear on a list item not on the list container? But yes the problem is the `role="listitem"` that is added as that tells the browser to expose that item as if it was a `<li>` to assistive technology.

Comment: We could do to see a fiddle for this if you want us to help you further, especially as the amp carousel examples don't seem to use an `<ul>` and rely on `<div>`s instead. Could you create a fiddle of a simple carousel. The linked issue is to do with a tablist not a carousel so it isn't much use (plus it is a missing `aria-role` not an incorrect one it seems)

Comment: IMHO there is no 'violation' that invalidates the page. Your reported error is not picked up by the W3C HTML validator. You may want to follow the advice here: https://amp.dev/page-experience/. But that is for "extra credit".